# How to return an optional<T> without an if statement?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std, option-type

Suppose I have a function which finds and returns the minimum element of a vector. If the vector is empty, it should return an empty optional object. Is there a way for me to use the `optional<T>` constructor to avoid using either an if statement or the ternary operator?

With if statement:

```
optional<Foo> GetMinElement(vector<Foo> foos) {
  vector<Foo>::iterator min_foo = std::min_element(foos.begin(), foos.end());
  bool found_min_element = (min_foo != foos.end());
  if (found_min_element) {
    return *min_foo;
  } else {
    return nullopt;
  }
}
```

With ternary operator:

```
optional<Foo> GetMinElement(vector<Foo> foos) {
  vector<Foo>::iterator min_foo = std::min_element(foos.begin(), foos.end());
  bool found_min_element = (min_foo != foos.end());
  return found_min_element ? optional<Foo>(*min_foo) : optional<Foo>(nullopt);
}
```

Naively, I'd just like to be able to pass the output of an `stl` algorithm to the `optional<T>` constructor and have it handle the logic of checking for a null pointer. Is there some idiom for this?

Comment: One cannot, looking at the iterator alone, determine whether or not it's dereferenceable. Which in itself is necessary but not sufficient: an algorithm could have been invoked over a range other than `(someContainer.begin(), someContainer.end())`. In light of this, a solution that doesn't involve calling code explicitly checking for "algorithm found something" appears unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that the end iterator is not a null pointer.  It can even be a valid iterator if the range was a subrange.

I write my own range algorithms.  They follow a different pattern than yours.

A range algorithm takes a `class Range`, does adl-enabled `begin`/`end` and runs an iterator algorithm.  It then returns an optional iterator (empty if it would be `end`).

This is slightly different than yours, because mine does not return a copy of an element.

And they can be used (with the addition of `make_range(start,finish)`) everywhere the originals are.

---

If you dislike the syntax of both if and `?`, these may help:

```
template<class T>
std::optional<std::decay_t<T>> maybe(bool engage, T&&t){
  if (!engage) return {};
  return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

or even:

```
templace<class F>
std::optional<std::decay_t<std::result_of_t<F()>>>
perhaps(bool do_it, F&&f){
  if (!engage) return {};
  return std::forward<F>(f)();
}
```

which short-circuits like `?` does.

```
namespace adl_helper{
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  template<class R> auto adl_begin(R&&)->decltype(begin(std::declval<R>())){
    return begin(std::forward<R>(r));
  }
  template<class R> auto adl_end(R&&)->decltype(end(std::declval<R>())){
    return end(std::forward<R>(r));
  }
}
using adl_helper::adl_begin;
using adl_helper::adl_end;

template<class R>using iterator_t=decltype(adl_begin(std::declval<R>()));

template<class R>
optional<iterator_t<R>> min_element(R&& r) {
  auto ret = std::min_element(adl_begin(r), adl_end(r));
  return maybe(ret!=adl_end(r), ret);
}
```

which I find is more useful than your version.

You do need to do an extra `*` sometimes, or use a helper.

Answer (score 2):

[optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/optional) does not seem to have a constructor that can sometimes yield an empty optional and sumetimes yield a full one.

Perhaps you could make a helper:

```
template<typename Iter>
optional<typename Iter::value_type> try_deref(Iter pos, Iter singular)
{
    if ( pos != singular )
        return *pos;

    return {};
}
```

Sample usage:

```
optional<Foo> GetMinElement(std::vector<Foo> const &foos)
{
    auto min_foo = std::min_element(foos.begin(), foos.end());
    return try_deref(min_foo, foos.end()); 
}
```

Comment: Alternatively the helper could accept `pos` and a boolean, and the usage would be `bla(min_foo,  min_foo == foos.end())`